# Accidentally sent money to donation address on bitcoin.org website

Tags: bitcoin-core, address, blockchain.info, client, bitcoin-cash

4 days ago I sended my money to Bitcoin wallet as a donation,I am new guy,and I did it wrong I wanted to transfer the money to my other wallet account to put it on my bank to buy food.now the money are gone,how I can take it back.Was the money for food till my next salary.Now the money are on Bitcoin org like a donation.Please help I have all proofs,and the transfer proof

Answer (score 3):

> how I can take it back

You can't *take* Bitcoin money. Confirmed Bitcoin transactions cannot be cancelled or reversed.

> Now the money are on Bitcoin org like a donation

If you sent money to the donation address on the Bitcoin.org website, the only way to get the money back is to contact the [website domain owner](https://bitcoin.org/en/about-us#owners), explain the mistake you made, and ask them to create a new transaction paying you a similar amount.